# Count rows grouped by months as columns

Tags: sql, datetime, pivot, amazon-redshift

I have the following data (actually spans over years but for this example, I only included 4 months)

```
id  created_at  staff
--------------------------------
1   2010-01-01  Coder
2   2010-01-15  Developer
3   2010-03-01  Data Analyst
4   2010-01-20  Developer
5   2010-03-13  Data Analyst
6   2010-04-05  Tester
7   2010-04-01  Tester
8   2010-04-04  Business Analyst
9   2010-01-22  Business Analyst
10  2010-01-25  Coder
```

I want to create a query that counts the number of `staff` for each year-month. Below is an example of the output I am expecting from this query.

```
staff               2010-01   2010-02   2010-03   2010-04   
----------------------------------------------------------
Coder               2         0         0         0
Developer           2         0         0         0
Data Analyst        0         0         2         0
Tester              0         0         0         2
Business Analyst    1         0         0         1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Redshift. Thanks, I amended the tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fixed list of months, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select staff,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_01,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-02-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_02,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_03,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_04
from mytable
group by staff
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It looked hopeful as I saw a table of all the months!! However, each column contained the value of the first month. What I failed to demonstrate in my original table is that the `created_at` is a timestamp so when date_trunc function is used it turns the time to `00:00:00`. Unsure if this is the cause of the issue?

Comment: Weird, I just ran through your query on sqlfiddle and it works... I wonder why it isn't working as expected on my redshift DB? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a59c3/2

Comment: i'm an idiot. I used the `count` function instead because I thought you made a typo with SUM.... Thanks for your help!